# Query displaying duplicates when table has unique values?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

i'm learning sql and trying to figure out how to incorporate data from 3 tables into a single query. I have 3 tables TASK, PROJECT, and PRIORITY_TYPE.

TASK lists all tasks in the database with a unique number task_id, a project_id that represents which project the task corresponds to, and priority_type_id which is a number that represents urgency in another table.

PROJECT is a list of all projects, completed or incompleted.

PRIORTY_TYPE lists all priority_type_id as a number with a corresponding priority_type_name that represents urgency. The numbers are different for each project (URGENT in 1 project does not have the same priority_type_id as URGENT in another). I would like to select all the tasks for incomplete/ongoing projects and their corresponding urgencies. I currently have the query

```
select task.task_id, task.project_id, task.priority_type_id
from task 
where task.project_id in (select project_id from project where completion < 100)
```

this displays all tasks from incomplete/ongoing projects with their unique task_id's, the project they correspond to, and the number of the priority_id to look up in PRIORITY_TYPE.

However, I would also like to include priority_type_name from the PRIORITY_TYPE table in the select. My attempt looked like the following query:

```
SELECT task.task_id, task.project_id task.priority_type_id, priority_type.priority_type_name
FROM task, priority_type 
WHERE task.project_id IN (SELECT project_id FROM project WHERE completion < 100)
```

However, this produces duplicate tasks with repeating task_id but different priority_type_name, even though each task_id only appears once in TASK. Could anyone point me in the right direction on this?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: It doesn't produce duplicates. It just produces a syntax error.

Comment: Define the join condition between priority_type & task table.

Answer (score 0):

Thats because its doing a cartesian product. The join key is not defined.

Query should be something like this:

```
SELECT task.task_id, task.project_id task.priority_type_id, priority_type.priority_type_name
FROM task, priority_type 
WHERE task.project_id IN (SELECT project_id FROM project WHERE completion < 100)
and task.project_id = priority_type.project_id
```

Answer (score 0):

using an `inner join` instead:

```
select
    task.task_id
  , task.project_id
  , task.priority_type_id
  , priority_type.priority_type_name
from task 
  inner join priority_type 
    on task.priority_type_id = priority_type.priority_type_id
where task.project_id in (select project_id from project where completion < 100)
```